# Another beta integral due to Cauchy.

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration, gamma-function, beta-function

I have the following identity which I want to prove:

$$C(x,y):= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(1+it)^x(1-it)^y} = \frac{\pi \cdot 2^{2-x-y}\Gamma(x+y-1)}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}$$ where $\Re(x+y)>1$.
I proved so far that $C(x,y) = \frac{2^{2n} (x)_n (y)_n }{(x+y-1)_{2n}}C(x+n,y+n)$ and that: $C(x+n,y+n) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^n(1+it)^x(1-it)^y}$; now they ask me to set $t\to t/\sqrt{n}$ and then let $n\to \infty$, I don't see what does this integral converge to?

P.S
Here I use the following notation: $(a)_n = a(a+1)(a+2)\ldots (a+n-1)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would try contour integration: Because the integral converges in uhp, u can pull ur path of integration up to infinity. Doing so u will enclose a brachcut starting at $t=i$. The resulting integral shouldbe nice enough to bring it into one of the standardrepresentations of the Beta function quiet quickly.

Comment: I second @tired suggestion.

Comment: @tired can you show me explicitly the calculation, since my complex integration is a bit rusty (I haven't done these sort of calculations for a long time, since my undergraduate studies). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @MartinNicholson the integral after the substitution is: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ds \sqrt{n}}{(1+s^2n)^n(1+is\sqrt{n})^x (1-is\sqrt{n})^y}$, how do you get that the integrand is asymptotic to $e^{-nt^2}$?

Comment: @MartinNicholson then what is asymptotic to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-nt^2}$, and how do you show it? thanks.

Comment: can anyone help me with this question? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
C(x+n,y+n) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^n(1+it)^x(1-it)^y} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{du/\sqrt{n}}{(1+u^2/n)^n(1+iu/\sqrt{n})^x(1-iu/\sqrt{n})^y} 
\qquad (\textrm{let }u=t/\sqrt{n}) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} e^{-u^2} + O(1/n) 
\qquad (\textrm{standard limit for }e) \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n}} + O(1/n) 
\qquad (\textrm{standard integral})
\end{align*}

Recall that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/n)^n = e$. 
Similarly, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+x/n)^n = e^x$. 
Thus, we find 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{(1+u^2/n)^n} = e^{-u^2}.$$
Also 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{(1+iu/\sqrt{n})^x}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{(1-iu/\sqrt{n})^y}=1.$$